# Reactjs como obtener un value dinámico y pasarlo al estado

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un problema, estoy pasando algunos valores como `defaultValues` en un par de `inputs` en react, la propiedad value me devuelve uno de los valores, el otro lo pude sacar usando `UseRef`, pero el valor se queda estático, y no cambia al seleccionar otro valor de el `input select`,
la idea de este componente es que cada vez que yo cambio de moneda usando el `input select`, automáticamente, se pasen los valores `public_key` y `private_key`, solo puedo obtener `private` que viene de el `value` y el `public`, lo intente sacar con el hook `useRef()` pero no es dinámico y me lo pasa al estado para todos las opciones,¿Que puedo hacer? gracias.

```
    import { useRef } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Blocks from './Blocks'

const Transaction = () => {
    const keyvalue = useRef()
    const [wallet,setWallet]=useState([])
    const [newTransaction, setNewTransaction]=useState({
        key:'',
        from:'',
        to:'',
        amount:'',
    })

    const setData = () => {
        let status = keyvalue.current.getAttribute("data-key");
        console.log("status", status);
      };

    useEffect(()=>{
        getWallets()
    },[])

    const handleChange= e=>{
        setNewTransaction({
            ...newTransaction,
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value,
            
        })`setData()`
    }

    const submitTransaction = e=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(newTransaction)
    }

    const cancelTransaction=()=>{
        window.location.href='/home'
    }

    const getWallets = async()=>{
        const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        const idUser = sessionStorage.getItem('idUser')
        const url = 'http://localhost:4000/wallets/walletslist/'+idUser
        const myHeaders ={
            method: 'GET',
            headers : { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              mode:'cors',
              autorization:token
             },
        }
        const request=await fetch(url,myHeaders)
        const response = await request.json()
        setWallet(response)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={submitTransaction}>
                <div>
                    <select name='key' onChange={handleChange}>
                        <option value="error">--select wallet--</option>
                            {wallet.map(wallet=>(
                                <option key={wallet._id} ref={keyvalue} data-key={wallet.public_key} value={wallet.private_key}>{wallet.name}</option>
                            ))}
                    </select>
                    <label>your sign address wallet</label>
                    <input type="text" style={{width:'500px'}} name='key' defaultValue={newTransaction.key} />
                    <label>your address wallet</label>
                    <input type="text" style={{width:'940px'}} name="from" defaultValue={newTransaction.from} />
                    <label>to address</label>
                    <input type="text" name='to' required  />
                    <label>amount</label>
                    <input type="number" name="amount" onChange={handleChange} required />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="send transaction" required />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type='button' onClick={cancelTransaction}>cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <Blocks/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Transaction;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho este pequeño ejemplo.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomSelect />
    </div>
  );
}

class CustomSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "car": ""
    }

    this.valueChanged = this.valueChanged.bind(this);
  }

  valueChanged(e) {
    if (e.target.name === "car") {
      console.log(e.target.name);
      console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.key);
      return;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="car">Choose a car:</label>

        <select onChange={this.valueChanged} name="car" id="cars">
          <option data-key="-1-data" value="-1">
            ...Select a car ...{" "}
          </option>
          <option data-key="1-data" value="0">
            Volvo
          </option>
          <option data-key="2-data" value="1">
            Saab
          </option>
          <option data-key="3-data" value="2">
            Mercedes
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Básicamente debes verificar si el nombre del elemento es el que quieres verificar su `data-key`. De ser así, dentro de un if, extraes el `data-key` y lo añades a tu estado.

En mi ejemplo solo hago un `console.log`, pero tu deberías cambiar eso por el correspondiente `setState`.

Puedes probar el código aquí:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-worker-9zkjw?file=/src/App.js:470-481

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo bastante